# Как применить стиль к тэгу <li> через jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть код который прекрасно работает для тэга `<a>`. Как применить его для тэга `li`?

```js
< script >
  $(function() {
    $('a[href="' + window.location.pathname + '"]').addClass('active');
  }); <
/script>
```

```css
<style>.active {
  background: #eec15b;
}

</style>
```

```html
<ul class="kt-nav main-menu clone-main-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="page1">page1</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Код криво написал. Конкретики мало. Вот как тебя понимать? Яснее выражайся.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href="' + window.location.pathname + '"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
например так
```

```js
$("li").css("background-color","red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="kt-nav main-menu clone-main-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="page1">page1</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```